# Regex for less than or equal to date field

Tags: regex

Given a date, would it be considered an anti-pattern to try and use a regex to determine whether the input is greater than or equal to a specific date? For example, let's say there is a DOB text field on a form:

```
DOB:   2011-02-49
```

And we want to make sure the user is More than X years old to do a purchase. For this example, let's say we want to make sure the user was born before 2010:

```
2010-01-01
```

I've used regex to do gte/lte integers, but it seems like matching with dates would be a bit trickier. How could this be done with a regex?

Comment: To validate the value entered is a date, using a regex is appropriate.  To compare the date with another date, that is not a good use case for regex.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't convert the date string to a DATE datatype or similar and then do the appropriate comparisons? This strikes me (pardon the pun) as using a hammer to pound a round screw into a square hole.

Comment: @BobJarvis Oh yes, of course. I would one-line this in python or maybe even js: `>>> parse('2008-01-01').date() < datetime.date(2010,1,1)  True`. I'm more just interested to see how this might be done (if possible) using regex.

Comment: This user was born on February 49th?  I guess the leap-years really piled up...

Comment: To check the user was born before 2010, you just have to check the year is 2009 or less, so it must match `^([01]|200[0-9])`.  But that's a lucky special case.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is **NOT** the optimal solution as each year this would have to be updated to accept new customers age X (as it's a new year). Add in the complexity of months and days and it falls apart pretty quickly into an ugly mess when attempting with pure regex.

If you know the date that the input has to be before (not dynamic) this is possible in regex

```
^(\d{1,3}|1\d{3}|200[0-9])-\d{2}-\d{2}
```

The main part to determine is the year (`(\d{1,3}|1\d{3}|200[0-9])`)

- `\d{1,3}` accepts years under 1000 (though unlikely)
- `1\d{3}` accepts from 1000 to 1999
- `200[0-9]` accepts from 2000 to 2009

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/c1MIWH/1)